# Div not stretching 100% width/height in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

Attempting to create a lightning component which will be wrapped by a div which is all white but it is not making up 100% of the width/height.

[image]

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">      
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%;" class="slds-grid slds-box slds-theme_default">     
        <div style="background-color:#2C4E33;" class="slds-col slds-m-horizontal_medium slds-theme_default" >
            <span> 1</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#E3CAA0;" class="slds-col slds-m-horizontal_medium">
            <span> 2</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#2C4E33;" class="slds-col slds-m-horizontal_medium">
            <span> 3</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#E3CAA0;" class="slds-col slds-m-horizontal_medium">
            <span> 4</span>
        </div>
    </div>     
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[slds-box](http://Provides%201rem%20base%20padding%20and%20borders) says:

> Provides 1rem base padding and borders

You're getting some padding because you're using slds-box. Remove that, and you should have the full width available. As an aside, it is not necessary to specify width on a div, because it uses 100% by default.